# repaint() method not working for tint image

Tags: java, paintcomponent, graphics2d, repaint

> Full project here
>   https://github.com/jafetrd/easyImageEditor

I'm trying to apply a color to an image using the paintComponent(), this is the class I use

```
public class Metodos extends JPanel{
...............................
........more code..........
................

public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
    System.out.println("entrecolor");
    repaint();
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(imagen != null){
        super.paintComponent(g);
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
              g2d.setXORMode(color); //this is the filter i want to repaint
                if(detectar==false){
                     g2d.drawImage(imagen, getWidth()/2 - nuevoTamaño.width/2, getHeight()/2 - nuevoTamaño.height/2, nuevoTamaño.width, nuevoTamaño.height, this);
                }else{
                     g2d.drawImage(imagen, posX-nuevoTamaño.width/2, posY-nuevoTamaño.height/2, nuevoTamaño.width, nuevoTamaño.height,this);
                }
           g2d.dispose();
        }
}
```

I call to setColor() from another class to send the color object and repaint the image with the XOR inside the paint component, but it's not working. The class from where I send the color looks like this:

```
 public final class Colores extends JFrame{
  JColorChooser jc;
  private Metodos m;
public Colores(){
        componentes();
        inicio();    
   m = new Metodos();
}

public final void componentes(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   // Metodos a = new Metodos();
    jc = new JColorChooser();
    jc.setPreviewPanel(new JPanel());
    jc.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener((ChangeEvent arg0) -> {
        m.setColor(jc.getColor());
        super.repaint();
    });

    add(jc);
    pack();
}
.........................
.........more code.........
...................................
```

> Here I take the color from the JColorChooser and send to the method 
>   setColor() and repaint the image, but it does not work at all.

Comment: Did you check call of overriden `paintComponent` method (for example, System.out)?

Comment: yes i checked that way, and because of that I realize that the repaint() method wasn't doing the work

Comment: I almost sure that if you rename `paintComponent` to `paint` (and change modificator to public) it's wil be work. But in oracle tutorials and documentation it's not recomended

Comment: I changed it but it doesn't work

Comment: the full code is here https://github.com/jafetrd/easyImageEditor :)

Comment: What is not working? Is the image not repainting, or is the color not repainted properly?

Comment: the image is not repainting with the new color

Comment: No one wants the full code, what you should provide is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem in as few lines as possible

Comment: Try to change line `super.repaint();` to `Colores.this.repaint();`

Comment: First, try the code with two different colors to make sure it actually changes the image the way you want. Then, you can trigger repaint events by resizing the window. There seems to be two possible ways to fail here.

Comment: I change Colores.this.repaint() and does not work, alse resize the window with different colors and didn't work,

Comment: In your `Colores` class, you create a new instance of `Metodos` ... what relationship does this have with the instance of `Metodos` on the screen?  How could the possible talk with each other?

Comment: mmmm, when i don't create the instance of **Metodos** it throws and nullpointerexception

Comment: I alse repaint the *Metodos* class from the Main class, but I first added it tom the main class in ths constructor like this **add(metodo);** and there the *Metodos* class works well

Comment: @user2461687 Do you understand the concept of passing references of objects to classes?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't realize about that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a basic example of a bad and misguided design.

In your `Colores` you create a new instance of `Metodos`...

```
public final class Colores extends JFrame{

    JColorChooser jc;
    private Metodos m;
    public Colores(){
       componentes();
       inicio();    
       m = new Metodos();
    }
```

In what way does this have anything to do with the instance which you created earlier and put on the screen?

You need to pass a reference of `Metodos` to `Colores`

Have a look at [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for more details

```
public final class Colores extends JFrame {

    JColorChooser jc;
    private Metodos m;

    public Colores(Metodos m) {
        componentes();
        inicio();
        this.m = m;
    }
```

And update `Metodos`

```
case Colores:
    new Colores(this).setVisible(true);
    break;
```

Things don't magically bind together, you actually need to provide the valid information to you program before it can work.

I would, however, encourage you to use a different mechanism.

`JColorChooser` actually has it's dialog support built in...

```
case Colores:
    Color newColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(this, "Colors", color);
    if (newColor != null){
        color = newColor;
        repaint();
    }
    break;
```

This allows the user to cancel the dialog if they don't want to select a color

Comment: I didn't know how to bind the two parts passing the parameters, Thanks, and I'll read more about it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a program that works. You need a png file to see the results.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class TintPicture{

    static Color[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("tinted");
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("sample.png"));
        int[] index = {0};
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
                g2d.setXORMode(colors[index[0]]);
                g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
            }
        };

        pane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
                index[0] = (index[0] + 1)%colors.length;
                pane.repaint();
            }
        });

        frame.setContentPane(pane);

        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

It includes using the xor, and changing/updating the display.

Comment: I don't see the reason this should get a downvote. It is a compilable example that does what the OP wants. It demonstrates, changing a color and what to call repaint on.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question - why is the `paintComponent` and `setColor` method not getting called - it's an example of code the OP already has and proofs only the code could work if the OP changed their entire application to fit your model - It's unfortunate that the OP has failed to add the one piece of code which would have helped, the code where they actually call `Colores` from within `Metodos` - with that you'd have been able to determine the actually cause of their problem and we could have missed all the "guessing"

Comment: @MadProgrammer  He said the paintComponent method is getting called. This just demonstrates, that calling repaint on the requisite component will cause it to repaint, and it demonstrates what they should be seeing when the XOR value is changed. It doesn't say anything about changing their application to fit my model.

Comment: The `paintComponent` wasn't been called in response to a change in the `Colores` class, it was impossible for `Colores` to call `setColor` on the instance of the `Metodos`, so there `paintComponent` wasn't been called in response to that change, it was more likely in response to the a system event. You'd have to see the code to understand - the unfortunate reality is, this just simply doesn't answer the OP's question - they can paint the original image, but could not get the color to update, the issue is not with the `paintComponent` method, but how they structured their solution